# MacBook Pro unibody doesn't restart properly after battery depletion

Tags: macbook, battery, reboot

My MacBook Pro (unibody, 13'', 2009) used to restart fine after battery depletion. The computer would automatically save the state of the system and reboot to whatever I was doing before. For those not familiar, a grayed out version of the screen before battery depletion shows up on reboot with a gray/white progress bar thing at the bottom.

Now I get some odd behavior. Battery runs out, I plug it in and leave it charging, then reboot. When I do, a grayed out screen *with my old windows open* shows up, but the progress bar stops halfway through.

Anyone know what's happening or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm you have enough free disk space for the hibernation, secondly i have the 15" model 2009, which also has a problem with the battery now, which results in also lose date and time.

Comment: Sure; I think I have enough free disk space. I've got at least 10GB and the RAM totals 4 GB